# Cakephp page pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have created my own `dataSource` that collects data using an API.

Now I am trying to use the paginate function to get the data. This works fine I am getting the right data however there is a problem!

I simply cannot get the paginator to identify pages. My goal is to make sure that there is only 50 records pr page however no matter what I do I only get **ONE** page and my links are not correct links they are basicly just text

Here is my view:

**index.ctp**

```
<?php

    $this->Paginator->options(array(
        'update' => '#updateTable',
        'evalScripts' => true,
    ));
    ?>



        <!-- BEGIN EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->
<div id="updateTable">

        <div class="portlet box green Report index">
        <div class="portlet-title">
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="report_data">
                <?php foreach ($table['Report']['data']['data'] as $res): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo h($res['Offer']['name']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><?php echo h($res['Stat']['clicks']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><?php echo h(round($res['Stat']['conversions'], 2)); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><?php echo "€ " . h(round($res['Stat']['payout'], 2)); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><?php echo h(round($res['Stat']['ltr'], 2)) . " %"; ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><?php echo "€ " . h(round($res['Stat']['cpc'], 2)); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div>
                <div class="paging">
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('first' => 'First page'));
                    echo $this->Paginator->prev('< Prev', null, null, array('class' => 'disable'));
                    echo $this->Paginator->next('Next >', null, null, array('class' => 'disable'));
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it is worth mentioning that I am using Ajax to paginate (if that matters)
It is also worth mentioning that the API im using to collect data does support pagination however I have not been able to find any documentation on how to "costumize pages" with the `paginator`

Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong or know how I fix this issue?

Comment: Add `<?php  echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>` before closing of `<div id="updateTable">`

Comment: Debug the count call the paginator does. I guess your datasource does not return the right count. You know how pagination works, conceptwise?